# How to return a single (non-LiveData) object from Room using Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines

Room executes queries that return `LiveData` on a background thread automatically. But I want to return a single value that is not wrapped into `LiveData` (because I don't want live updates).
How do I implement this using coroutines?

How do I return the `Task` object from this function?

```
fun getTask(id: Int): Task {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.getTask(id)
    }
}
```

This function is inside the ViewModel. It forwards the call down to the DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE id = :id")
fun getTask(id: Int): Task
```

Comment: You can't make synchronous (immediate) returns from coroutines.  That's not how they work.  Coroutines are asynchronous, and the consumption of their data has be asynchronous all way up to the final consumer.  This is why LiveData exists - use it, even if you think it's too complicated.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your answer. The reason I don't want to use `LiveData` is that this value is not supposed to get live updates on the screen. I suppose I could still return `LiveData` and just read it's `value` once but that doesn't seem like a clean solution. After all, it's called *live* data.

Comment: LiveData is a perfectly good solution for single responses. In fact, the documentation even confirms this with it "resource" pattern.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Do you have a link you can point me to regarding the part of the documentation you mentioned?

Comment: `@Query(...) suspend fun getTask(id: Int): Task`, also you can use `Flow` with `Room` instead of `LiveData`

Comment: Pretty much this entire page discusses how LiveData fits into generalized app architecture, even for data sources that are not "realtime live", such as standard network requests. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#recommended-app-arch

Comment: There is a `SingleLiveEvent` class, basically, LiveData that will only send an update once. I think using this approach is alright. You can find the implementation here: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

Comment: @Hawklike looks exactly like what I need, thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you don't return a LiveData from Room you won't get updates from the DB. You can however return a LiveData from your viewModel.

```
val data = liveData {
    emit(repository.getTask(id))
}
```

The `liveData` extension function runs in a coroutine and then you can use the suspend version of your DAO to handle backgrounding properly.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun getTask(id: Int): Task?
```

A big thing you need to do is make sure it is nullable if you aren't using an aggregate function in your query.

If you are really wanting to call the method in your viewModel to return the task you should run the launch from your activity/fragment (not recommended)

```
ViewModel
suspend fun getTask(id: Int): Task {
    repository.getTask(id)
}

Activity/Fragment
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val task = viewModel.getTask(id)
    // Do What you want with the task
}
```

Comment: the question is how to return the value from the supsend function

Answer (score 3):

## Flow is the new LiveData!

I had a similar problem in two project before, each solved differently. But recently I learnt to use `Flow` and it appears that it is the cleanest way yet.

### Alternative to LiveData

If you don't need to use LiveData you have two option:

1. Retrieving a `Cursor` by a @query, suitable for refactoring old projects.
2. Using `Flow`, suitable for new projects.

### Retrieving only one object/value

1. LiveDate: You can unsubscribe from the LiveData, remove the observer after the first fetch. Not clean way in my opinion.
2. Flow: You can retrive just a single object/value if you want and then stop the flow collecting.

#### **Dao:**

getTask(): this method return a `Flow<Task>`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE id = :id")
fun getTask(id: Int): Flow<Task>
```

#### **ViewModel:**

getTask(): return a `Task` object (not `Flow<Task>`), also it is `suspend` function.

> **first()** The terminal operator that returns the first element emitted by the
>   flow and then cancels flow’s collection. Throws NoSuchElementException
>   if the flow was empty.

```
suspend fun getTask(id: Int): Task {
    return dao.getTask(id).first()
}
```

#### **Fragment/Activity:**

Properties:

```
private var viewModelJob = Job()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
```

*don't forget to cancel viewModelJob when fragment/activity not needed aka onClear/onDestory/... so that all coroutines tight to this is canceled.*

#### **Usage**

Now whenever we want to retrieve our object `Task` from that suspended function we need to be inside a suspend or coroutine. Therefore using `launch` builder to create a coroutine is suitable here (since we don't want any return object from that builder we only want to run a suspend function, otherwise async to return a deferred).

```
    onCreate() / onCreateView()
    .
    ..
    ...
    uiScope.launch() {
        // Here are the Task & Main-UI
        val task = viewModel.getTask(1)
        binding.taskTitleTextView.text = task.title
    }
```

If we don't use `first()` then we need to collect the flow `viewModel.getTasks().collect{ it }` there are many useful function at [kotlinx.coroutines.flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/index.html). `Flow is` the best thing that happen in Coroutine Package, and oh sorry that I pass the repository layer, it is just a duplicated for viewModel in most cases .

Answer (score 2):

> Suspend functions in Room are main-safe and run on a custom
> dispatcher. Same as LiveData as you mentioned in your question. Below is the example to achieve the same
>
> Inside some function in viewmModel class

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
       // suspend and resume make this database request main-safe
       // so our ViewModel doesn't need to worry about threading
       someLiveData.value =
               repository.getSomething()
   }
```

> In repository class

```
suspend fun getSomething(): List<Something> {
   return dao.getSomething()
```

}

> In Dao class

```
 @Query("select * from tableName")
   suspend fun getSomething(): List<Something>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround would be to return Deferred object immediately and then call `.await()` on the return deferred

```kotlin
fun getTaskAsync(id: Int): Deferred<Task> = viewModelScope.async {
        repository.getTask(id)
    }

//call-site
getTaskAsync(id).await() // <- this is suspension point
```